# Mathematic non linear equation solver

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, exponential, nonlinear-functions

I need to solve below equation for the x using mathematica,basically i need numberical values for x,interms of A,B,K,a and b

Ax^(-a)+Bx^(-a-b)=K

Comment: Okay, what have you tried? The best Sage can do for five variables is this: `x^b = (K*x^(a + b) - B)/A`

Comment: There's a page on [numerical equation solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalEquationSolving.html) on the Mathematica site.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for numeric solutions in Mathematica, check out its `NSolve` function ([documentation here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html)). For example:

```
x = NSolve[A x^(-a) + B x^(-a - b) == K, x]
```

Of course, to use a numeric solver, you'll have to have already set numeric values for the five variables in question.

That's a vague answer to a vague question -- if you give us more information, we may be able to give you more specific, and more helpful advice.